# v does not name a type error with c++ vectors

Tags: c++, vector

I'm currenty starting with C++ and trying to change the value of a vector like that:

```
std::vector<float> v = {0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0};
v[5]= 1.0;
```

But I get an error: `error: ‘v’ does not name a type`

Comment: Did you include the appropriate header? `#include <vector>`

Comment: Is this the only error you get? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Did you include these statements in a function, e.g. in `int main() { ...`?

Comment: Please provide [mcve]. Your example is not one, because it lacks `main` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your code snippet copied to the file scope of a source file (i.e. a part outside any function), I get a similar error message. So I am sure you forgot to put the code inside a function.

Write

```
int main() {    
    std::vector<float> v = {0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0};
    v[5]= 1.0;
}
```

and it should work as intended.